# How can i get a touch event of uiImage view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiimageview, touch

i have a UIImageView named as myImageView.
  i need to set the userInteractionEnabled for this UIImageView.
so i used myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

However still myImageView is not responding to any User interaction.

Can any one tell me a good way to enable touch event on myImage View and also i need to get the myImageView image , when touch event is triggered.can any one help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an implementation for one or more of the touch events, such as `touchesEnded:withEvent:`,  in your view controller.  The first parameter to that method is the set of touches that triggered the event.  You can get more details in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom UIButton instead UIImageView of an  and set its image to the image you want to display in the UIImageView. Then you can add an action to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];
```

Where drawImage is your ImageView